# Get the filename of a fileupload in a document through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, file-upload

```
var fu1 = document.getElementById("FileUpload1");
```

How can I get the filename of the fileupload control with `id FileUpload1`?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try the `value` property, like this:

```
var fu1 = document.getElementById("FileUpload1");
alert("You selected " + fu1.value);
```

**NOTE**: It looks like `FileUpload1` is an ASP.Net server-side FileUpload control.
If so, you should get its ID using the [`ClientID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) property, like this:

```
var fu1 = document.getElementById("<%= FileUpload1.ClientID %>");
```

Answer (score 61):

In google chrome element.value return the name + the path, but a fake path. Thus, for my case I used the name attribute on the file like below :

```
function getFileData(myFile){
   var file = myFile.files[0];  
   var filename = file.name;
}
```

this is the call from the page :

```
<input id="ph1" name="photo" type="file" class="jq_req" onchange="getFileData(this);"/>
```

Comment: Note to others: for IE11 this didn't return anything for me.

Answer (score 27):

To get only uploaded file Name use this,

```
fake_path=document.getElementById('FileUpload1').value
alert(fake_path.split("\\").pop())
```

`FileUpload1` value contains fake path, that you probably don't want, to avoid that use split and pop last element from your file.

Comment: accepted answer is good. but this is perfect if you need the file name without fake path for reuse in fetch/post, or button labels ect.,

Answer (score 4):

Using code like this in a form I can capture the original source upload filename, copy it to a second simple input field.  This is so user can provide an alternate upload filename in submit request since the file upload filename is immutable.

```
    <input type="file" id="imgup1" name="imagefile">
      onchange="document.getElementsByName('imgfn1')[0].value = document.getElementById('imgup1').value;">
    <input type="text" name="imgfn1" value="">
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Try `document.getElementById("FileUpload1").value` this value should have a path for a file to be uploaded, just strip all dirs from that value and you will have file name.

Answer (score 3):

RaYell,
You don't need to parse the value returned.  `document.getElementById("FileUpload1").value` returns only the file name with extension.
This was useful for me because I wanted to copy the name of the file to be uploaded to an input box called 'title'. In my application, the uploaded file is renamed to the index generated by the backend database and the title is stored in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var fu1 = document.getElementById("FileUpload1").value;
```