# file extension verification in java script

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can the file extension be validated in an input type file using JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041854/how-can-the-file-extension-be-validated-in-an-input-type-file-using-jquery)

this is my file Extension verification code to prevent unwanted files uploaded

is there a much simpler method to code this?

can anyone improve on this?

```
<script>
function onSubmitForm(re) {
    var formDOMObj = document.frmSend;
    var file1 = formDOMObj.attach1.value;

    var pdf=file1.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf(".pdf");
    var doc=file1.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf(".doc");
    var docx=file1.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf(".docx");
    var xls=file1.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf(".xls");
    var xlsx=file1.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf(".xlsx");
    var wps=file1.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf(".wps");


    if (file1  == "" )
    {
        alert("Please pick a file.")
        return false;
    }
    else
    if ( pdf == -1 && doc == -1 && docx == -1 && xls == -1 && xlsx == -1 && wps == -1 )
    {
        alert("File not acceped. Please upload your RESUME in .pdf, .doc, or docx")
        frmSend.reset(re);
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Be sure to verify on the server too; an attacker could just disable your client-side verification code and upload a restricted file anyway.

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796537/input-type-file-limit-selectable-files-by-extensions

Comment: Although, if you have things set up in such a way that a malicious upload could actually cause problems, you’ve got bigger problems. (Re: @voithos’ comment)

Comment: @minitech: `alias attacker='naughty-user'`

Answer (score 5):

To simplify that:

```
var extension = file1.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
var allowed = ['pdf', 'doc', 'docx', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'wps'];

if(allowed.indexOf(extension) === -1) {
    // Not valid.
}
```

Of course, a file doesn’t necessarily contain what its extension says it contains.

Comment: +1 for `.split().pop()` to get the extension

Comment: I guess you can remove `xlsx` from that list... ;-)

Comment: @Arjan: ... why? That’s `allowed.indexOf`, by the way :)

Comment: What if a file named "pdf" would be uploaded ? ^^

Comment: @Glutamat: Well, there is that! :D It’s pretty easy to rename a file, though, so may as well assume that `pdf` is a PDF :) Although, for correctness' sake: `if(file1.indexOf('.') === -1 || allowed.indexOf(extension) === -1) { ... }`

Comment: @minitech :P just saying ^^ But you are right, in the end it doesn't really matter if you don't check the file content, you can always just rename the file

Comment: Ha, you're right minitech, I failed to realize it's `Array#indexOf`, not `String#indexOf` at work here!

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions are powerful.

```
function onSubmitForm(re) {
    var formDOMObj = document.frmSend;
    var file1 = formDOMObj.attach1.value;

    var acceptedTypes = ["pdf", "doc", "docx", "xls", "xlsx", "wps"];
    var re = new RegExp("\\.(" + acceptedTypes.join("|") + ")$");

    if (file1  == "" )
    {
        alert("Please pick a file.")
        return false;
    }
    if (!re.test(file1))
    {
        alert("File not acceped. Please upload your RESUME in .pdf, .doc, or docx")
        frmSend.reset(re);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}​
```

Comment: shouldn't that be `!re.test(file1)` ?

Comment: yes, it should. updated, thanks.

Comment: Might want to include a `\.` before there, just to make sure `.rdoc` (or something) files aren’t accepted. (Not really a huge issue for client-side validation, though.)

Comment: Indeed, but who knows =)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need this code use accept inside your tag

```
<input type="file" accept="application/pdf,application/msword">
```

Comment: `accept` should contain MIME types, not extensions.

Comment: My fault, corrected, thanks @minitech

Comment: And: much more friendly for operating systems that do not rely on file extensions to determine a file type.

Comment: You are right @Arjan solid as rocks OS don't rely on file extension.

Comment: I’m really not sure about `accept` for things like Word documents, though, and browsers(/OSes?) that may or may not recognize them. For example, in Firefox on Linux for me, this doesn’t filter anything.

Answer (score 0):

You could also assign the extension to a var and
do a switch case on it, this way you could handle different actions too if you ever want to,thats one other possible shorter solution

```
function onSubmitForm(re) {
    var formDOMObj = document.frmSend;
    var file1 = formDOMObj.attach1.value;
    var ext = file1.match(/\.(.+?)$/)
    ext = ext == null ?"NONE": ext.ext[1].toLowerCase();

    switch (ext) {
        case "":
            alert("Please pick a file.")
            return false;
        case "pdf":
        case "doc":
        case "docx":
        case "xls":
        case "xlsx":
        case "wps":
            return true;
        default:
            alert("File not acceped. Please upload your RESUME in .pdf, .doc, or docx")
            frmSend.reset(re);
            return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: What if a file without an extension is uploaded?

Comment: You might want to add a null check before indexing

Comment: @fastreload Thx, just realized this, a length check would do fine, wouldn't it ?

@ Arjan
 it would run into the default case

Comment: It won't, `match` method returns `null` instead of `[]` when there is no match; I guess it is done for using that in `if` statements as `!![]` is `true` while `!!null` is `false`

Comment: Oooh, that's correct, it would result in a type error with a length check.
Mh thats interesting, didn't ever thought about why it is returning `null`, instad of `[]`

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier to read just using a straight RegExp:

```
function onSubmitForm(re) {
    var formDOMObj = document.frmSend;
    var file1 = formDOMObj.attach1.value;

    if (file1  == "" )
    {
        alert("Please pick a file.")
        return false;
    }
    if (!/\.(doc|docx|pdf|wps|xls|xlsx)$/.test(file1))
    {
        alert("File not acceped. Please upload your RESUME in .pdf, .doc, or docx")
        frmSend.reset(re);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about anyone else, but this really says _"file1 ends with .doc or .docx or .pdf ..."_ more clearly than some of the more concise answers.