# Get FileName using JavaScript [POST]

Tags: javascript, forms

How do I get the name of the file uploaded to a form (post) with a code similar to this:

```
frm.name.value  
frm.password.value
frm.email.value
```

How can I get the name of frm.file? I want the "synonym" of **$_FILES["FILE"]["NAME"]**.

Need pure JavaScript code without jQuery please.

According to the HTML5 API should be **frm.file.name** but that doesn't works. It's returning null on the basadate.

Comment: Keyword: HTML5 File API.

Comment: Do you need this before the file is posted to the server, or in the response afterward?

Comment: You could take a look at this [previously answered question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804745/get-the-filename-of-a-fileupload-in-a-document-through-javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="file" onchange="alert(this.value)" />
```

That will alert `C:\fakepath\filename.extention` for most browsers. You can then cut off the beginning to get just the file name.