# How to generate AWS S3 pre-signed URL request without knowing Content-Type?

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I am generating in server side a pre-signed URL request with the following parameters for [GeneratePresignedUrlRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/GeneratePresignedUrlRequest.html) : `bucket`, `key`, `expiration = in 1 hour` and `method = PUT`.

In my Angular app, I am uploading the file using [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload)

```
Upload.http({
    url: $scope.signedUrl,
    method: "PUT",
    headers : {
        'Content-Type': $scope.file.type
    },
    data: $scope.file
});
```

The problem is that I always have a `403` response unless I set the type of the file in `GeneratePresignedUrlRequest.contentType`.

The problem is that I can't predict in advance what type of file the user will choose (`image/png`, `image/jpeg`, `text/plain`...).

How can I generate a pre-signed url that accept all kinds of `content-type` ? I tried setting it to null, it keeps sending 403 errors.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I just ran into this problem, and just got it working. Replace your Upload.http code with the following:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("PUT", $scope.signedUrl);
reader.onload = function(evt) {
  xhr.send(evt.target.result);
};
reader.readAsArrayBuffer($scope.file);
```

The problem ends up being that S3 is looking for a specific Content-Type (`binary/octet-stream`), which it infers when you omit the Content-Type header.

Answer (score 4):

The value from the `Content-Type` header is a mandatory component of the signature.  It isn't possible to pre-sign a `PUT` URL without knowing the value that will be sent.

A `POST` upload is more flexible, since you can allow any Content-Type in the signed policy.

Comment: What do you mean by `POST` upload ? Get the pre-signed URL with `POST`, no content-type and `POST` instead of `PUT` in my Angular app ?

Comment: It doesn't particularly matter how you get the authorization from your back-end, but S3 has a very different interface for form-based uploads using a `POST` from the browser that seems to be a better match for what you are doing, at least in this one sense: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html

Comment: Actually, you might start here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-UsingHTTPPOST.html

Comment: Thanks but I can't use HTML POST form. The form needs to be independant.

Comment: You technicallyvdon't have to "use" (build, render, or display) a form, you only have to submit the structure of a form back to S3.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot do you think my issue is in presigning part or the content uploading part? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72979158/how-to-set-type-for-uploading-file-to-s3

Answer (score -3):

One possible solution might be if you keep track of the extension?
eg: ends with ".jpg" -> content type = "image/jpeg", end with ".zip" -> content type = "application/octet-stream".

Ref: [get the filename of a fileupload in a document through javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804745/get-the-filename-of-a-fileupload-in-a-document-through-javascript)

Comment: This does not address core part of the question: cannot predict file type in advance