# How to access the name property of an uploaded file (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, html

I've gone through other similar threads and am not finding my answer, if I missed it, apologies for the duplicate.

I have a simple event handler for file submission with a form. It is as so:

```
onChange(e) {
    let files = e.target.files;
    console.log(files);
  }
```

The console log is:

```
FileList {0: File(692), length: 1}
0: File(692)
lastModified: 1546326376754
lastModifiedDate: Tue Jan 01 2019 00:06:16 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time) {}
name: "userFile.txt"
size: 692
type: "text/plain"
webkitRelativePath: ""
__proto__: File
length: 1
__proto__: FileList
```

I would like to `console.log(files.name)` and get `userFile.txt` returned. I am getting `undefined`. Very sorry if this has been answered a million times, I've spent a long time searching and trying different dot notations etc. to no avail. Thanks

Comment: FileList {0: File(692), length: 1}, it's an array of size 1, does that tell you what to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get the filename of a fileupload in a document through javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804745/get-the-filename-of-a-fileupload-in-a-document-through-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it by `files[0].name`

```js
function getFileName(e) {

  let files = e.target.files;
  console.log(files[0].name);
}
```

```html
<input type='file' onchange='getFileName(event)'>
```

Comment: lovely, will accept when in a few minutes when the site lets me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to access the `0` property in `files` like so:

```
console.log(files[0].name);
```

And it should work.

Demonstration:

```js
function getFileName(event) {

  const files = event.target.files;
  console.log(files[0].name);
}
```

```html
<input type='file' oninput='getFileName(e)'>
```

Comment: No problem @HanleySoilsmith, glad I could help!