# how to get http request upload file name at php?

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

```js
function fileupload () {

    var data = new FormData(),
    PMfile = document.getElementById("PMfile").files;
    data.append("file", PMfile[0]);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "upload.php", true);
  
    xhr.send(data);
    return false;
}
```

```html
<input onchange="fileupload()" type="file" id="PMfile" name="PM_file" class="form-control" required>
```

I want to get the file name at upload.php
I tried `$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];` but this doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the filename of a fileupload in a document through JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804745/get-the-filename-of-a-fileupload-in-a-document-through-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

This is correct and should work.
Dump whole $_FILES and inspect if you get what you want.
For me it displays this:

```
Array ( [file] => Array ( [name] => example.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpBQOHQl [error] => 0 [size] => 48316 ) )
```

So `$_FILES['file']['name']` is going to be `example.jpg`

But if i upload a file that is too big for my current php settings i get $_FILES as `Array ( )`  so it is empty and in apache logs i have:

```
[Tue Jul 07 21:04:25.535907 2020] [:error] [pid 7729] [client 127.0.0.1:37234] PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of 21138710 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0, referer: http://localhost/a.php
```

So my guess is - code is correct (if there are no errors in js/html you dont show us) but upload has an error - check your error logs.